# scraping all the links in a webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to get the links of markets on this webpage https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/monthly/klines/
but it's not working. Actually I can get links but only those from the header. I think my problem is to build the target path, examples :

```
Elements tableLinks = doc.select("#listing a");

Elements tableElement = doc.getElementsByAttribute("tbody");

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

Elements resultLinks = doc.select("td > a");
```

Comment: It looks like the table content of that site is loaded async via JavaScript. You say you can get the links in the header - do you mean the links above the table? Your issue may be that you’re loading the html but not using a scraping tool that evaluates the JavaScript / loads the table of links from the server.

Comment: yes i can get all the links above the table... do you have an idea of what tool i should use to evaluates the js ?

Comment: Do you just need all links once or are you programming something to scrape them multiple times? The page uses this API to get the links, you could just do an HTTP GET call and then scrape into the respone: 

https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/data.binance.vision?delimiter=/&prefix=data/spot/monthly/klines/&marker=data%2Fspot%2Fmonthly%2Fklines%2FONEBIDR%2F

Answer (score 1):

The table which includes the links you are looking for is added to the DOM by Javascript after the initial page load. In order to be able to get that content you need to to simulate a browser. For example you can use [HtmlUnit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/) which is a GUI-Less browser for Java programs. Use html unit to access the page and wait a while until the javascript code is executed and the table is loaded. Afterwards you can parse the page as usual with jsoup.

Maven repo HtmlUnit:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/monthly/klines/";
        
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);        
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
        
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml());
        Element tbody = doc.getElementById("listing");
        Elements links = tbody.select("a[href]");
        
        links.forEach(link -> {
            System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For this site/use case you may also be able to simulate the Ajax request and get the table/links directly (though this approach is probably better in that it is more generic and less dependent on the specific sites implementation).

Comment: There is no need to convert the page to XML and then parse with Jsoup - you can select all the thinks you need with HtmlUnit also (start here https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html and read 'Finding a specific element')